# Изменить значение поля в зависимости от значения в другом поле

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Как изменить значение поля в зависимости от значения в другом поле?
Например, есть поля **price** и **price_string**, нужно для всех записей, где **price** = 0 заполнить поле **price_string** значением **договорная**

Для обновления поля во всех записях я использовал такой запрос:

```
UPDATE products
SET price_string = 'договорная'
```

Вопрос, каким образом можно добавить условие для обновления только определенных записей?

Comment: `WHERE price = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать оператор `WHERE`

```
UPDATE products
SET price_string = 'договорная'
WHERE price = 0
```